# Return to main after thread has ended

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently messing around with facial recognition and try to capture photos form my webcam. I am adapting [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-a-snapshot-from-system-camera-using-opencv-in-java/) tutorial to automatically name and save the taken picture. Note that this Code is called from the main() the funtion it self is implemented in another class. Up and until I stop the thread with interrupt() it works. Afterwards the picture is frozen in the GUI and the system doesn't seem to return into the class where I operate over my GUI.
To make myself clear: I want to capture a picture from my webcam and replace the former stream from my webcam with said earlier captured picture. Up and until I capture the picture and interrupt the thread the code works. Aftwards it is stuck.
I experiemented with pulling the Thread into the ActionListener of the CaptureButton but that failed because the main GUI element was not accessible which is courious given that it is defined as public.
It does however throw in the course of compilation some warnings - tho I must admit that I have no clue what they mean:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (376) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (388) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:1] global C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1021) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -1072873821
Exception in thread "Thread-0" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:896: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !image.empty() in function 'cv::imencode'
]
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imencode_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imencode(Imgcodecs.java:510)
    at GUI.FaceRecognition.startCamera(FaceRecognition.java:129)
    at main$1$1.run(main.java:19)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ WARN:2] global C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Thread vorbei
```

I have written my code rather amateurish of that I am sure and I reckon I could use something like callable() but am unsure who to use that. I also do not know how to replicate my problem outside of chucking my entire project around the internet but I can however provide the code of my modifications:

- for the funtion itself

```
public boolean startCamera(){
       capture= new VideoCapture(0);
       image=new Mat();
       byte[] imageData;
       ImageIcon icon;
       String name = null;
       boolean echo = false;
       while(true){
           capture.read(image);
           final MatOfByte buf=new MatOfByte();
           Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", image,buf);
           imageData= buf.toArray();
           icon=new ImageIcon(imageData);
           Feed.setIcon(icon);
           if(trigger==true){
               name="Recognition";
               Imgcodecs.imwrite("src/"+name+".png",image);
               trigger=false; //Auslöser zurücksetzten
           }
           File kamera=new File("src/Recognition.png");
           if(kamera.exists()==true){
               //capture.release();
               /*try {
                   Kamera=ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Recognition.png"));
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }*/
               return echo=true;
           }
       }
   }
```

- for the main()

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.String;
import GUI.*;
import org.opencv.core.Core;


public class main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    FaceRecognition Fenster=new FaceRecognition();
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //FaceRecognition Fenster=new FaceRecognition();
            new Thread (new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Fenster.startCamera();
                }
            }).start();
            //File kamera=new File(("src/Recognition.png"));

        }
    });
    if(Fenster.startCamera()==true){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.out.println("Thread vorbei");
    }

}
}
```

Please point out where I went wrong or what goes wrong.

**Edit:**
I have mean while heeded @pveentjers advice and reformed my code (see below). Yet in my main() the IDE proposes to make startCamera static which will not work because startCamera can not be static (or rather elements of it can't). Is there any way to move around this?

- the startCamera function

```
public class startCamera implements Runnable{
        private CountDownLatch end;

        public startCamera(CountDownLatch one){
            this.end=one;
           }
        @Override public void run(){
            try {
                capture= new VideoCapture(0);
                image=new Mat();
                byte[] imageData;
                ImageIcon icon;
                String name = null;
                while(true){
                    capture.read(image);
                    final MatOfByte buf=new MatOfByte();
                    Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", image,buf);
                    imageData= buf.toArray();
                    icon=new ImageIcon(imageData);
                    Feed.setIcon(icon);
                    if(trigger==true){
                        name="Recognition";
                        Imgcodecs.imwrite("src/"+name+".png",image);
                        trigger=false; //Auslöser zurücksetzten
                    }
                    File kamera=new File("src/Recognition.png");
                    if(kamera.exists()==true){
                        capture.release();
                        end.countDown();
                /*try {
                    Kamera=ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Recognition.png"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception){

            }

        }
```

- the reformed main()

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import GUI.*;
import GUI.FaceRecognition.startCamera;
import org.opencv.core.Core;


public class main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    FaceRecognition Fenster=new FaceRecognition();
    CountDownLatch mark=new CountDownLatch(1);
    startCamera startCamera=new startCamera(mark);
    try {
       mark.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Might be that I don't the wood for the trees but this the first time I am working with threads.

Comment: You could create a CountDownLatch(1) in the main thread and pass it to the Runnable and on completion do a latch.countDown. In your main thread do a latch.await(); This will force the main thread to synchronize on the completion of the Runnable. I didn't have a very close look at your code, starting a new thread from the EventQueue looks a bit funky.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that it might look weird becasue I copy-pasted the code from the tutorial into my basic GUI and try to work form there. Do you know a resource for absolute beginners on threads?

Comment: Oracle has a rad tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  The section on Threads is called [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).